# Spring Data Rest: Adding Element to Collection

Tags: spring, rest, post, collections

this [link][1] demonstrates how to add an element to an existing collection:

```
    $ curl -X POST -v -d 'http://localhost:8080/people/1' -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/family/1/members
```

When I am trying the same thing with my project I am getting 405 Method Not Allowed:

```
mathias@id83:~$ curl -X POST -v -d 'http://localhost:8080/poll/cashFlows/230' -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/poll/products/221/cashFlows
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /poll/products/221/cashFlows HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/uri-list
> Content-Length: 40
> 
* upload completely sent off: 40 out of 40 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: null, X-Xrsf-Token, Accept, Content-Type
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800
< Access-Control-Allows-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
< Allow: GET, DELETE, PATCH, PUT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1140
< Date: Thu, 26 Feb 2015 08:19:57 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Pivotal tc Runtime 3.0.2.SR2/8.0.15.B.RELEASE - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'POST' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
the requested resource.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Pivotal tc Runtime 3.0.2.SR2/8.0.15.B.RELEASE</h3></body></html>mathias@id83:~$ 
mathias@id83:~$
```

Here my entities:

```
@Entity
public class CashFlow extends PersistentEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private Integer dailyRate;

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Integer getDailyRate() {
        return dailyRate;
    }

    public void setDailyRate(Integer dailyRate) {
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Product extends PersistentEntity {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Stats stats;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CashFlow> cashFlows;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Stats getStats() {
        return stats;
    }

    public void setStats(Stats stats) {
        this.stats = stats;
    }

    public Set<CashFlow> getCashFlows() {
        return cashFlows;
    }

    public void setCashFlows(Set<CashFlow> cashFlows) {
        this.cashFlows = cashFlows;
    }

}
```

And finally the repositories:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

}
public interface CashFlowRepository extends CrudRepository<CashFlow, Long> {

}
```

Why is this not working in my project?

cheers
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PUT or PATCH method..